# Is Kernel-General time sync event linked with CPU usage?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, cpu-usage

We are running 6 2008 SQL Servers on Windows Server 2008 R2, 4 of which were sitting around 50%+ CPU usage during peak usage. On Wednesday, the CPU on 2 of these 4 servers dropped by 20% and performance greatly increased on our production service.

I can't see any immediate reason for this decrease in CPU usage, but the Event Viewer shows a "Kernel-General" event at the exact time the CPU usage decreased on both servers. The message was: "The system time has changed to ‎2017‎-‎11‎-‎29T14:56:49.967000000Z from ‎2017‎-‎11‎-‎29T14:56:36.200429700Z."

Could this have had any impact on CPU usage, or is this entirely coincidental? If so, why would this have any impact?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming an event was logged at the same time is related. This is not necessarily true as the event logs cover a broad range of things possibly not related to performance.

Take a step back and describe the system and the problem statement completely. Consider approaches like [the USE method](http://www.brendangregg.com/usemethod.html):

> For every resource, check utilization, saturation, and errors.

Find relevant tools to measure these in your environment based on documentation and the experience of others.  For example, TechNet has a document [Troubleshooting Performance Problems in SQL Server 2008](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd672789(v=sql.100).aspx) that shows practical examples of perfmon and SQL Server Profiler.